# Angular 4 logout issue

Tags: angular

I have some components in angular app like header, footer, sidebar, login, admin etc.
Now header and sidebar should not be shown in login page for some reasons. But other component like admin should see the header and sidebar. For this reason in app.component.html I have done as bellow:

```
<div id="app">

<app-header *ngIf="router.url !== '/'"></app-header>
<!-- END HEADER -->


<div class="clearfix">
</div>
<!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->
<div class="page-container">

<div *ngIf="router.url !== '/'"><app-sidebar></app-sidebar> </div>

  <div class="page-content-wrapper">

    <div class="page-content">



      <router-outlet>
      </router-outlet>
      <app-new-patient></app-new-patient>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Now problem is when I want to logout it shows error.

In header.component.ts

```
logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }
```

In header.component.html

```
<li>
   <a ng-click="logout()" href="">
   <i class="icon-key"></i> Log Out </a>
</li>
```

The route

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes=[
{path:'', component: LoginComponent},
{path:'admin', canActivate:[AuthguardGuard], component: AdminComponent},
{path: 'search',  component: PatientSearchComponent },
];
```

The error message

[image]

Could you please help me?

Comment: It seems you configure some route to redirect to login.html, and there is no such route. Post the route definitions.

Comment: @JB Nizet : Route is provided above.

Comment: Somewhere in the code you're trying to route to login.html. That appears in the error message. But it never appear in the code you posted. Look for login.html in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `navigateByUrl` method as it expects absoulte path.

[image]

Your code will add a slash at the end of the current route and there is no such definition which logs this error

Update 1 : 
Add pathMatch and move it to last in the order of route definitions

```
{path:'', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have given this.router.navigateByUrl('/'); But shows same error.

Comment: You need to give the complete path what is ur route definitions look like

Comment: Yes sure. But I think I have given complete path, is n't it?

Comment: Hello Aravind, found the problem at last. Thing was I was using Angular 4. But here I used a syntax from AngularJs ng-click which should be (click). That's way the application was malfunctioning. Anyway thanks man for your great support.